# Spring Boot+Hibernate Rest Api Controller getting status 404

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am creating a simple CRUD application following some tutorial  using spring boot and Hibernate,I am getting 404 error when trying to access my api's through postman app,i went through 
[Spring Boot: Cannot access REST Controller on localhost (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31318107/spring-boot-cannot-access-rest-controller-on-localhost-404) and [404 not found while testing spring boot rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554675/404-not-found-while-testing-spring-boot-rest-api) and [Spring boot + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796818/spring-boot-hibernate) none of them helped.

Controller Class is:-

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/students/")
public class studentController {

@Autowired
private StudentService service;

@RequestMapping(value="getstudent",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public Collection<Student> getStudent(){
    return  service.getStudent();
}
@RequestMapping(value="getstudent/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public  Student getStudentById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    return service.getStudentById(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="getstudent/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public  void deleteStudentById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
     service.deleteStudentById(id);
}
@RequestMapping(value="updatestudent",method=RequestMethod.PUT,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void updateStudentById(@RequestBody Student student)
{
    service.updateStudent(student);
}
@RequestMapping(value="createstudent",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void createStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
    service.addStudent(student);

}}
```

The service class is:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("mysql")
public class StudentService {

@Autowired
private  StudentDaoInt dao;

@Transactional
public Collection<Student> getStudent(){
    return  dao.getStudent();
}
@Transactional
public  Student getStudentById(Integer id){
    return dao.getStudentById(id);
}
@Transactional
public void deleteStudentById(Integer id) {

     dao.deleteStudentById(id);
}

@Transactional
public void updateStudent(Student student)
{
    dao.updateStudent(student);
}
@Transactional
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    dao.addStudent(student);

}
```

The Dao class looks like:-

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("mysql")
public class StudentDaoMySql implements StudentDaoInt{

@Autowired
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf){
    this.sessionFactory = sf;
}
@Override
public Collection<Student> getStudent() {
  return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student").list();

}

@Override
public Student getStudentById(Integer id) {
     return (Student) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Student s wehre s.id=id").list();
}

@Override
public void deleteStudentById(Integer id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE from Student s wehre s.id=id").executeUpdate();

}

@Override
public void updateStudent(Student student) {
    Query q=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("update Student  set name=:myname,age=:myage where id=:myid");
    q.setParameter("myname", student.getName());
    q.setParameter("myage", student.getAge());
    q.setParameter("myid", student.getId());
    q.executeUpdate();


}

@Override
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(student);

}
```

and the app.java class:

```
@ComponentScan({"spring","hibernate"})
@SpringBootApplication()
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
}
```

The package structure looks like:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZ24.jpg

The application.properties file content:-

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestRest
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = dinga
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =       org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

In the console server is running fine and table is also created but i am getting 404 error when trying to access the api's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Application.properties file i added

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

and in the app class i added

```
@Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
```

This created the session factory object and i was able to perform CRUD operation with this Sessionfactory object.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
@ComponentScan({"com.student.studentdb"})
```

And you need inject LocalSessionFactoryBean instead of SessionFactory

```
   @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;
```

then use that to get session

```
 Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

Comment: when i add com.student.studentdb and change to @ComponentScan({"spring","hibernate","com.student.studentdb"})

Comment: i got the exception

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: how about adding @EnableAutoConfiguration to the Application class

Comment: what is the url did you try @shashank

Comment: in the postman app for getting the records   http://localhost:8080/students/getstudent